# Wishlist api in magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist

I install wish-list module in our project. When i call any API of this module it showing some error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Ipragmatech\Ipwishlist\Api\WishlistManagementInterface in /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer-&gt;create('Ipragmatech\\Ipw...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(305): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager-&gt;get('Ipragmatech\\Ipw...')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;processApiRequest()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Intercept in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_v2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php</b> on line <b>73</b><br />
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/946085665948"}]}}
```

Anybody help me for removing this error.

Comment: Have you tired clearing cache and recompiling ?

Comment: I will run both commands setup:upgrde and cache:clean.

Comment: setup:di:compile ?

Comment: I didn't run setup:di:compile command.

Comment: Please do let me know after running the command also hope your review issue is solved